# Change icon and label text in addin commands ribbon

Tags: office-js

Is there a way to dynamically change the icon and label text in addin commands in custom tabs in a Ribbon? I've created an Excel menu ribbon with button (with manifest.xml) and want to change the icon and text whenever the user clicks on the button. Like a toggle switch.

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported, but it has been suggested. Please go to [Office Dev User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/), search on "ribbon", and you will find similar suggestions that you can vote up.

Comment: Hi, is this still not supported or has it been implemented? Thanks

Comment: Dont think it is still supported, added feedback here for MS team - https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/53517248-68ca-ee11-92bd-6045bd7b0481